# DispatcherTimer первый вызов Tick сразу при старте C#

Tags: c#

Как сделать, чтобы при запуске таймера он сразу выполнил код в прикрепленном методе, а не дожидаться отсчета интервала.

Например:

```
 var makeWorkTimer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15) };

        makeWorkTimer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");              
        };

        makeWorkTimer.Start();
```

Как сделать, чтобы cw выполнился сразу, не дожидаясь 15 секунд интервала на первый запуск метода?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var makeWorkTimer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15) };

EventHandler handler = (sender, args) =>
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hello");              
};

makeWorkTimer.Tick += handler;
makeWorkTimer.Start();
handler(null, null);
```

Comment: Отлично, но лучше вызывать так: `handler(this, EventArgs.Empty)`

Comment: Все работает, только тип *handler'a* нужно заменить на **System.EventHandler** вместо **Action**

Comment: @Ep1demic, поправил.